# Let F be a function defined for all nonnegative integers by the following recursive definition

Tags: logic, recursion, sets, counting

Let F be a function defined for all nonnegative integers by the following recursive
definition.
F(0) = 0, F(1)= 1
F(n + 2) = 2F(n) + F(n +1), n>0
Compute the first six values of F; that is, write the values of F(n) for n = 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Well, I'm sure you can do it yourself.

Comment: In fact, the problem cannot be solved because we can't know $F(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(n)=a^n$ and assume that the recurrence also holds for $n=0$.

Then

$$a^{n+2}=2a^n+a^{n+1}$$ so that

$$a^2-a-2=0$$ and $a=-1,2$.

By the theory of linear recurrences, the general solution is of the form

$$c_+2^n+c_-(-1)^n.$$

The initial conditions tell us that $c_++c_-=0$ and $3\,c_+=1$.

Hence

$$F(n)=\frac{2^n-(-1)^n}3.$$

Now plug $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Answer (score 0):

$$F(0)=0,\\F(1)=1,\\F(3)=2F(1)+F(2)=F(2)+2\\F(4)=2F(2)+F(3)=3F(2)+2,\\F(5)=2F(3)+F(4)=5F(2)+6.$$